# Dates and times: "on", "in", "at"?

Tags: prepositions, difference, in-on-at

I’m often confused when I speak about times and dates. What is the rule for using *on*, *in*, and *at* in the following sentences?

- I will do it ___ Tuesday.
- We married ___ March.
- He returned ___ the same day.
- Every day ___ the same time, I walk the dog.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Times usually get *at*.

> Everyday *at* the same time I take a walk.
>   *At* 3 PM, I will be having a late lunch.

Days usually get *on*.

> I will do it *on* Tuesday.
>   He returned *on* the same day.

Months usually get *in*.

> We married *in* March.

Answer (score 7):

From what I know, confirmed by [here](http://www.englishclub.com/grammar/prepositions-at-in-on-time.htm):

- **at** for a precise time;
- **in** for months, centuries, years;
- **on** for days and dates;

Though I have seen **at** for days in the plural (e.g. *at Mondays*), but it looks rather informal in my opinion.

Comment: I've also seen "at Mondays", but usually in the writing of someone whose first language was something other than English.