# A maine coon is a type of cat

Tags: word-usage, generic-noun-phrases

I am confused about the usage of the word "*type*".  Take the following for example:

> 1. A maine coon is a **type** of cat.

which most people believe is correct standard English.  But, dictionary definitions define "*type*" as a group with similar qualities.  So, a "*type*" is really plural, not singular.  This seems to make sentence 1 wrong, with "*a maine coon*" being singular.  It seems that the correct version of sentence 1 would be:

> 2. A maine coon is ***a member of*** a ***type*** of cat.

What do native speakers think?  Is sentence 1 correct after all because it is idiomatic , and is sentence 2  unnatural?

Comment: In favor of reopening: This question is nearly impossible for a non-native to answer with a dictionary. It relates to subtle knowledge about the difference between "type" and "class" that most native speakers only hold subconsciously. Many dictionaries misleadingly define a type as a "group" or "category", saying nothing about why it's weird to speak of "a member of a type" but natural to speak of "a member of a class".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Meatie, I think your guess [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/70341/a-maine-coon-is-a-type-of-cat#comment134511_70341) is exactly right, and it's an excellent observation. I had never noticed it until you pointed it out. Even though "type", "kind", "class", "category", and "set" are all synonyms, it is indeed unnatural to speak of "a member of" a type or kind. The idea of membership or belonging makes sense with class, category, and set, but not type or kind.

### type

Etymology explains the difference in thinking that makes **type** incompatible with **member**. Echoes of old usages of these words, preserved in contemporary stock phrases and compound words, still color the way we understand them. Since [Ancient Greek](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CF%84%CF%8D%CF%80%CE%BF%CF%82#Ancient_Greek), **type** (in various forms) has primarily meant striking an object to produce an impression or image, the object struck, or the image produced. For example, printing presses used **movable type** until the 20th century, and people **typed** letters on **typewriters**. Since the same block of metal produces a nearly identical image each time it is struck, it's natural to extend **type** to mean the image considered abstractly, or indeed *anything* considered abstractly, like a type of animal or a **personality type**. The metaphor is that each animal of the same type is like another image struck from the same block.

This leads you to think of the abstraction as existing separately from all its instances, like [Ideas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory_of_Forms) in Plato's philosophy, or like a model that copies are made from. You can see this way of thinking in the words **prototype**, [meaning](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/prototype#English) a single model of something to be manufactured in large quantity when the design is perfected; **archetype**, [meaning](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/archetype) the ideal form of something that recurs in many different forms; and **stereotype**, [meaning](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/stereotype#English) a simplistic mental image of a class of people. These and many common usages of the word "type" tend to make people think of an abstraction as a sort of image or model when they hear or say the word "type".

### member

The word **member** comes from the Latin word for a limb—that is, a *part* of the body, like an arm or a leg. It retains this [meaning](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/member#English) in English, and in general people think of **members** as parts of a larger whole. The relationship of part to whole does not make sense with the metaphor of a model or block of type from which images are struck or copied. That is why we don't normally speak of a "member of a type".

### How to say it

Usually, people say that an individual is **of** a type, or they use the possessive case, like this:

> This cat is **of** the Maine Coon type.
>
> This cat**'s** type is Maine Coon.

If you really want a noun, you can use **instance**, which does not suggest a part-whole relationship. It sounds a little clumsy, but this usage is common in software engineering:

> This cat is **an instance of** the Maine Coon type.

The determiner (an article like **the**, **a**, or **an**, or an adjective like **this** or **that**) indicates whether the name of the type refers to the type or to a particular instance. Note that omitting a determiner is itself a determiner, and means that you are referring to the type, not to an instance:

> **Maine Coon** is a type of cat.
>
> **The Maine Coon** is a type of cat.
>
> <strike>**A Maine Coon** is a type of cat.</strike> [Usually wrong, because **a** introduces an instance. This does occur, however, in definitions, where people supply an article (or lack of an article) to indicate the common usage. Ask a separate question about that and I'll explain more.]
>
> This cat is **a Maine Coon**. [Correct: it means "This cat is an instance of the Maine Coon type."]

### Modern pressures to abandon the metaphor

The above describes ordinary, lay usage. In computer science, the words **class** and **type** have specialized meanings. The word **type** denotes a **set** for which some proposition is known to be true of all its members, and the word **class** denotes a data structure and some program code that is associated with it. For example, "nonnegative integer" is a type; it is known that every nonnegative integer can be added to a number, and that every nonnegative integer is greater than or equal to zero. An important question is whether the proposition known to be true of a type cannot be satisfied, meaning that the set is empty—has no members. If so, this suggests that the program that defines this type contains an error.

This peculiar set of meanings has created a strong pressure to abandon the metaphor of the "model or ideal from which copies are made", and speak of "members" of types. You'll find it especially common in the field called "[type theory](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=%22type+theory%22+%22member+of+the+type%22&btnG=&as_sdt=1%2C15&as_sdtp=)".

Similarly, in philosophy and mathematics, people often want to use the word **type** in a specialized way, to denote a kind of set. So, you'll occasionally see **member** combined with **type** in those fields, too. As usual, there is no precise rule governing all usage of the word **type**. As with all words, people extend and vary old and familiar usages to communicate what they want to say now.

Comment: The way I see it, "type" is not synonymous with "class", "set", or any other word that means collection. "type" is concerned with definitions, not the set of objects which fulfill that definition. For example, the word "pastries" in "pastries are a type of food" does not mean "the set of all pastries" but rather the concept of a "pastry". And we don't think of definitions as collections. This is just the way I conceptualize the word, I suppose other speakers might see it differently.

Comment: Sorry, could you please clarify: "**A** Maine Coon is **a** type of cat." is wrong because of the first **a**? Or because of the second **a**?

Comment: @CopperKettle It's hard to explain both briefly and accurately. My first thought is that rather than blaming one **a** or the other, the problem with the sentence is that it half-fits two common phrasings: "A Maine Coon is a  cat" and "The Maine Coon is a type of cat." And actually, if someone asks you "What's a Maine Coon?", a correct and grammatical answer is "A Maine Coon is a type of cat" (because you're echoing the phrase from the preceding sentence).

Comment: If one wants to be really pedantic -- [Maine Coon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maine_Coon) is a [breed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breed), not a [type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_%28biology%29).

Comment: -1 because, quite simply, *A Maine Coon is a type of cat* is grammatical and felicitous and idiomatic and natural and all that jazz, as my forthcoming, simple answer will demonstrate. @CopperKettle.

Comment: @GoDucks Did you see my comment above? As usual with English, there's _some_ context where the construct sounds natural even if out of context it doesn't. For this questioner, I figure it's most helpful to focus on the most "central", ordinary usage. I'd be delighted if you could suggest a way to cover the ability for "a Maine Coon" to stretch beyond its most ordinary usage without drowning the main idea with exceptions and corner cases. On the other hand, did you _intend_ your comment to suggest an improvement? Usually if you have a competing answer, the best way to suggest it is to post it.

Comment: @BenKovitz -- As I am sure you know, there are two common meanings of "<a> is a member of type <b>" in computer programming, neither of which is analogous to the original poster's attempted usage.  In both meanings, <b> is a "type" that consists of "methods" and/or "properties".  In one meaning, <a> is one of those "methods" or "properties" that <b> consists of.  In the other meaning, there is a third type <c>;  <a> is both one of the "methods" or "properties" that <c> consists of, and is an instance of type <b>.

Comment: The original poster's attempted usage is similar to 'A Maine coon cat is an instance of the type "Maine coon cat", which is a subtype of the type "cat".'  That last sentence is an example of computer programming jargon, rather than ordinary English.

Comment: @Jasper Did you see the section titled "Modern pressures to abandon the metaphor"? I thought it necessary to mention something about how some fields are starting to use "type" like "class" or "set", contra everything I said above, even though talking about those exceptions might induce some confusion. Indeed "member" has a variety of technical senses, too, but I'm worried that going into those would cause unhelpful confusion. If you have an idea for how to make the "member" section more useful without drowning out the main idea, I'd certainly consider it.

Comment: On the other hand, in the Plain English programming language, "a" is a keyword that is used to define variables as being of particular types, and to define new subtypes.  In this language, it is valid to say that "A Maine coon cat is a cat with a bobbed tail."  (If "cat" has already been defined as a type, and "bobbed tail" has already been defined.  The resulting type will be a subtype of "cat", and will have a member variable with type (and name) "bobbed tail".)  One could then define a variable, like so:  "Stumpy is a Maine coon cat."

Comment: @BenKovitz -- I was responding to that section.  I think the "modern pressures" are pushing in different directions than would lead to the original poster's attempted usage.

Comment: @Jasper Ah, now I see. (It can be hard to see every intended connection in the cramped form of 600-character comments!) I didn't intend for that section to suggest that "is a member of a type of cat" is becoming accepted usage, but apparently it came across that way to you. I mean only that the ancient and pretty durable metaphor of "type", explained above, has been eroded in some kinds of modern jargon, so the OP shouldn't take it as the last word on the topic or treat it as a rule. Can you point to anything in particular that might have led to the misunderstanding?

Comment: @CopperKettle I added some explanation of when the first "a" in "A Maine Coon is a type of cat" is OK, along with an invitation to ask another question.

Answer (score 5):

> I am confused about the usage of the word "*type*".  Take the following for example:
>
> > 1. A maine coon is a **type** of cat.
>
> which most people believe is correct standard English.  But, dictionary definitions define "*type*" as a group with similar qualities.  So, a "*type*" is really plural, not singular.  This seems to make sentence 1 wrong, with "*a maine coon*" being singular.  It seems that the correct version of sentence 1 would be:
>
> > 2. A maine coon is ***a member of*** a ***type*** of cat.
>
> What do native speakers think?  Is sentence 1 correct after all because it is idiomatic , and is sentence 2  unnatural?

Short Answer: Sentence 1 is correct, standard and idiomatic English. Sentence 2 is most unnatural.

Sentence 1 is so correct, standard and idiomatic that a sentence using its exact structure begins the description of the titular subject of the 2015 children's reader *[Life Story of a Salamander](http://www.capstonepub.com/classroom/products/life-story-of-a-salamander-1/)*, published by the educational publisher [Capstone](http://mycapstone.com/).

[image]

([source](https://books.google.com/books?id=L-P0AwAAQBAJ&pg=PA4&dq=%22a+salamander+is+a+type+of+animal%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjIqLK5n7rKAhUpmYMKHQ0pBL8Q6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=%22a%20salamander%20is%20a%20type%20of%20animal%22&f=false))

And **type** is not "really plural," it is singular. Its plural is **types**. What appears to be throwing you off is the word *group*, which is notionally plural. Many dictionaries do not use the word *group* when defining type; instead they use such words as *category*, *kind*, *sort*, which—like type—are singular in number.

---

You say

> "dictionary definitions define "type" as **a group** with similar qualities" (my emphasis)

This is true of definitions found in *some* dictionaries. For instance, Cambridge Dictionary proffers such a definition when it defines *type* as

> a ​particular ​group of ​people or things that ​share ​similar ​characteristics and ​form a ​smaller ​division of a ​larger set ([Link](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/type))

and MacMillan offers the following:

> a group of people or things with similar qualities or features that make them different from other groups ([Link](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/type_1))

With these definitions in mind, it is natural that the sincere learner might be confused when coming across sentences such as

> A maine coon is a type of cat

and

> A salamander is a type of animal

[***TO WIT***](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/to-wit?a=british): If a type is a group and a group must be plural, how can **a** (which refers to one) maine coon or **a** salamander be plural? This almost sounds like a trick question.

It is worth noting, first, that although *group* is notionally plural (it refers to more than one item), it can be grammatically singular. *Group* is a collective noun and may take either a singular or plural noun, [depending on what you mean](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/663/27803), that is, whether you construe *group* as a single unit or as a disparate throng.

Next, Oxford online, noting that it is "treated as singular or plural," defines *group* as

> A number of people or things that are located close together or are considered or **classed together** (my emphasis) ([Link](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/group))

Note Oxford's use of *classed together* as part of its definition of *group*.

This brings us to *group* as a synonym for *type*, *kind*, *sort*, etc., and we can construct sentences similar to the originals as

> A type or kind or sort or category or class or group of cat is a maine coon.

and

> A type or kind or sort or category or class or group of animal is a salamander.

This is not the most common use of *group*; for instance I doubt we would often find

> A maine coon is a group of cat

but it is just possible, if we use *group* as a synonym for *type*, *kind*, *class*, *category*, etc.

Definitions in other dictionaries avoid this source of potential confusion by not using *group* in their definition of *type*. Here are two found in the [OneLook Dictionary search](http://www.onelook.com/?w=type&ls=a) for *type*.

> A category of people or things having common characteristics
>   (Oxford)
>
> a kind, class, or category, the constituents of which share similar characteristics (Collins)

Meanwhile, the Oxford English Dictionary gives

> 6a A kind, class, or order as distinguished by a particular character (OED)

The structure that you ask about is not only correct and standard and idiomatic, it is common and plentiful. Examples abound in, for instance, Google Book searches.

Note that some examples are straight from the world of linguistics:

> (140) **An** X is **a** kind/type of Y
>
> Thus a lion is a type of animal, a snake is a type of reptile, etc.
>   ([Source](https://books.google.com/books?id=kZ9UwscjShEC&pg=PA195&dq=%22is+a+type+of+animal%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwivirnpv7nKAhWFPiYKHR-TAngQ6AEIIjAB#v=onepage&q=%22is%20a%20type%20of%20animal%22&f=false))

Many others, not surprisingly, are from the worlds of semantics, philosophy, cognitive science, etc that deal with definitions or representations of classes or types.

> Compare: if I tell one of my grandsons that **a lynx is a type of cat**, he immediately knows a great deal about lynxes because he already knows a great deal about cats. ([Link](https://books.google.com/books?id=nQMPIGd4baQC&pg=PA808&dq=%22is+a+type+of+cat%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwim9deRwrnKAhVC4CYKHdk9Dl8Q6AEIKzAC#v=onepage&q=%22is%20a%20type%20of%20cat%22&f=false))

One comes from the [extended usage note](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/sort-type-and-kind) regarding the words *sort*, *type*, and *kind* that is linked to from the definition of *type* found in the same Cambridge dictionary with which I started this answer.

> **A fastener is a type of metal button** which fits together to join clothes, for example a coat might have fasteners.

The list of usages is potentially endless because it is such a common usage/structure:

> [a sparrow is a type of bird; a wasp is a type of insect](https://books.google.com/books?id=9TyIAAAAQBAJ&pg=RA1-PR90&dq=%22is+a+type+of%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjs2sHeurrKAhUFroMKHfooAsA4ZBDoAQgnMAI#v=onepage&q=%22is%20a%20type%20of%22&f=false)
>
> [A poodle is a type of dog in the same way that a great white is a type of shark.](https://books.google.com/books?id=mvPMAH7V5GYC&pg=PT22&dq=%22is+a+type+of%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwja6KOoubrKAhVHuYMKHVP2ALE4MhDoAQhDMAc#v=onepage&q=%22is%20a%20type%20of%22&f=false)
>
> [an *ampersand* is a type of punctuation...](https://books.google.com/books?id=d76lkv4UrJgC&pg=PA82&dq=%22is%20a%20type%20of%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwie87zgsbrKAhVIl4MKHZL8D7UQ6AEIVTAJ#v=onepage&q=%22is%20a%20type%20of%22&f=false)
>
> [A meatus is a type of canal.](https://books.google.com/books?id=WrTwAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA32&dq=%22is%20a%20type%20of%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiowsO7srrKAhVstYMKHR2DDbQ4ChDoAQgbMAA#v=onepage&q=%22is%20a%20type%20of%22&f=false)
>
> [In fact, a gel is a type of sol in an intermediate physical phase](https://books.google.com/books?id=iZVCN05SURsC&pg=PA317&dq=%22is%20a%20type%20of%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiowsO7srrKAhVstYMKHR2DDbQ4ChDoAQhHMAg#v=onepage&q=%22is%20a%20type%20of%22&f=false)
>
> [A lid on a glass jar is a type of screw...A see-saw is a type of lever...a screwdriver is a type of pulley...an axe is a type of wedge](https://books.google.com/books?id=9sKpi-JpsfgC&pg=PA68&dq=%22is+a+type+of%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjJ1MCXs7rKAhXGg4MKHTLRA8E4FBDoAQg5MAU#v=onepage&q=%22is%20a%20type%20of%22&f=false) (Four uses in the space of eight test questions)
>
> [A so-called kegger is a type of house party at which the attendees drink beer that is pumped from a keg into plastic cups...A rave is a type of dance party that involves dancing to loud electronic music played by a DJ](https://books.google.com/books?id=YtsxeWE7VD0C&pg=PA603&dq=%22is+a+type+of%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjJ1MCXs7rKAhXGg4MKHTLRA8E4FBDoAQhNMAk#v=onepage&q=%22is%20a%20type%20of%22&f=false)
>
> [“Fast chess is a type of chess game in which each side is given less time to make their moves than under the normal tournament time controls of 60 to 180 minutes per player”](https://books.google.com/books?id=yvS5BQAAQBAJ&pg=PA73&dq=%22is+a+type+of%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjcpL7PuLrKAhVnk4MKHYdRArI4HhDoAQgnMAI#v=onepage&q=%22is%20a%20type%20of%22&f=false)
>
> [In contrast, a taxis is a type of orientation in which the animal directs its body toward or away from the stimulus.](https://books.google.com/books?id=coIbBXCG3GAC&pg=PA171&dq=%22is+a+type+of%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi46-mburrKAhWlmIMKHetaAL84WhDoAQgbMAA#v=onepage&q=%22is%20a%20type%20of%22&f=false)
>
> [An observational study is a type of study in which individuals are observed or certain outcomes are measured and no attempt is made to affect the outcome.](https://books.google.com/books?id=VTSUZ3nQvf4C&pg=PT26&dq=%22is+a+type+of%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjs2sHeurrKAhUFroMKHfooAsA4ZBDoAQgtMAM#v=onepage&q=%22is%20a%20type%20of%22&f=false)

Etc., [ad infinitum](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ad-infinitum).

Answer (score 3):

"Is a type of" already implies that it belong to the type, or group, of cats.
In this sentence "a type of cat" means that the maine coon is one of the many cat subspecies, so it's not plural.

I don't think the second sentence makes much sense at all. Maybe you can rewrite it as "A maine coon is a member of the cat type", but even that does not sound right to me. I would rather say "A maine coon is a member of the cat family".

To me "type" is singular, not plural.

Answer (score 3):

The correct way to say it would be "The Maine Coon is a type of cat." Using "a" instead of "the" does match common usage, but it only works because any one ("a") Maine Coon is a member of the type/breed 'Maine Coon'.

Answer (score 1):

If by "A Maine coon" you are referring to a breed then sentence 1 is correct and sentence 2 is incorrect.  If you mean a particular representative of the species, an actual single animal, then sentence two would be correct. Consider:

A cat is a type of animal.
This cat is a member of a type of animal, namely 'cats'.

Comment: Also a type with multiple members is still a singular type.

Comment: The usage of "*type*" in everyday English suggests that "*type*" is a singular thing, not a group of things. So "*a thing belongs to* ***a type of*** *thing*" sounds weird. But "*a thing belongs to* ***a class of*** *thing*" sounds okay. I might be wrong

Comment: Well a singular type can certainly contain multiple representatives.  I'm not sure where the misapprehension is but consider this.  "What type of car is that?"  "A Ford"  And of course there are multiple Fords.  Even the subject could be plural.  "Those cars, what type are they?" "They are Fords"  Note the type is still singular.  Of course "make" would be the better word in this example, but the generic "type" can be used.

Answer (score 1):

Re **“**

> dictionary definitions define "type" as a group with similar qualities

**”**; Dictionaries differ by comprehensiveness (Best ones at that include <dictionary.reference.com> and <thefreedictionary.com>. (Cf googl [QKNH3f](http://goo.gl/QKNH3f).)); ≪type≫ can mean:

  1: a group.

  2: an instance of "1".

---

Re **“**

> A maine coon is a type of cat.

**”**; This is legit; the writer most likely uses the 2nd meaning.

---

Re **“**

> A maine coon is a member of a type of cat.

**”**; This is legit; the writer most likely uses the 1st.

---

Re **“**

> is [≪A maine coon is a member of a type of cat.≫] unnatural?

**”**; Definitely not in contexts where its default alternative can be very ambiguous.

---

Btw:

Depending on context, ≪A Maine Coon is a cat.≫ can be very **ambiguous**. When you say it, you probably mean this:

[image]

But without context, the reader may think you mean this:

[image]

To disambiguate, you'll have to say ≪**Every** Maine Coon is a cat.≫.