# Is "A number of..." plural or singular?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

Is the following sentence correct?

> A number of researchers are expected to attend the conference

Notice that the sentence is using the plural verb "are" after "researchers" but I don't know if it needs the singular verb "is" instead, since it says "A number" before "researchers".

Comment: *A* number *are* expected.  *The* number expected *is* astounding.

Comment: There is a bucket load of answers suggesting that it depends [on the context](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/35265/a-lot-of-ideas-is-or-are#comment118624_37597) in which the word is being used. And by bucket load, I mean that there are at least two.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Idiomatically, the expression *a number of* works the same way as words and phrases like *many*, *several*, *quite a few*, or *plenty of*. Therefore, it's:

- Many researchers **are** expected to attend.
- Several researchers **are** expected to attend.
- Quite a few researchers **are** expected to attend.
- Plenty of researchers **are** expected to attend.
- A number of researchers **are** expected to attend.

Comment: Thanks J.R. You answered my question just right, thank you very much.

Comment: Oddly, this one can be different used definitely than when used indefinitely. ***A** number of researchers **have** noted that **the** number of researchers involved in their field **is** falling.*

Comment: Easy way to remember it - "a number of", let's call the number 'x': "x researchers are" -- oh, that was easy :)

Comment: @tchrist - In the first case, the verb is relating specifically to the researchers.  In the second, it's relating specifically to the *number*.  Using a different word: "***The** team of researchers **are** looking into the reasons that **a** number of researchers **are** leaving the field*."

Comment: @DarrelHoffman That may be a bad example. "The team of researchers is [...]" is perfectly valid and commonly used, and would be appropriate in your example. You may want to read up on collective nouns. See for example http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/collectivenoun.htm and http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/658/the-group-of-fifty-people-is-are-going-to-arrive-thursday-which-is-prefe

Answer (score -2):

Does double plural bother you? "Researchers" can be taken as a a job classification, The statement said that there are a indeterminate group of "men/women? going to join that are researchers. Singular would have said one of a group of researchers.

What is the meaning of "IS"