# 'Have' or 'Has' with groups

Tags: word-choice, american-english, word-in-context, collective-nouns

Edit: This might be a [duplicate](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/658/the-group-of-fifty-people-is-are-going-to-arrive-thursday-which-is-prefe), but I could not find a similar sentence (like mine) in any of the other questions.

I have seen many questions on this topic on [SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1338/are-collective-nouns-always-plural-or-are-certain-ones-singular) and [forums](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/a-group-who-has-who-have.1744922/). But I came across this sentence in a scientific article and was confused about the usage.

> The eggs were harvested from our colony which **have** been *in rearing* for over 4 generations.

Using the info from the links given, I feel that if the sentence had specifically mentioned 'colony ***of ants***', I feel '*have*' would have worked. Is this an AE/BE thing? The article, I believe, was written by an American.

Since the 'colony' is the subject, I feel 'has' would be more appropriate. Am I right?

Comment: It is just badly written. Neither colony nor eggs can breed. The subject is nominally eggs. It should have which were instead of were.

Comment: I feel like there is a missing "we" and a missing comma: _"The eggs were harvested from our colony, which we have been breeding for over 4 generations."_

Comment: @user2617804 - I'm really sorry. I made a mistake when typing the sentence. I've changed the word 'breeding' to 'in rearing' (which was the phrase used in the original sentence).

Comment: Thanks for checking. The original is still bad English- it reads like they wrote one sentence "The eggs were harvested from our colony" and then appended on more words that should in another sentence.

Comment: SteveES- this would typical general style- keeping it all passive.

Comment: The meaning of "in rearing" is unclear, as to whether it is referring to either  the eggs and the colony (as a business for example). But I think in regular usage you wouldn't rear eggs like you would babies, and you would "grow" a business not rear it.

Comment: @user3169 -In the 'Materials and Methods' section of [http://journal.frontiersin.org/article/10.3389/fevo.2015.00026/full] article, a similar expression is used. It uses the phrase 'the strain has been in rearing'. I believe the author in my article is referring to the colony he was raising for scientific study.

Comment: In a technical sense maybe it is OK. But in your question "Since the 'colony' is the subject", actually "eggs" is the subject. In general you can omit prepositional phrases without changing the basic meaning. In your example then, "The eggs were harvested which *have* been in rearing for over 4 generations." in which case *have* is correct.