# “At the first of the month” or “on the first of the month”?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, time, in-on-at

I'm writing documentation for a computer script I wrote. I'm wondering which I should say:

> 1. The script should run **at** the 1st of every month.
> 2. The script should run **on** the 1st of every month.

Comment: *On* is used with specific days and dates, *at* with times, *in* with timespans (centuries, years, months)

Comment: I believe [this question](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/12/dates-and-times-on-in-at) provides the answer you seek. “At” would be used for an exact time (8:30 am on that day, for example), “on” is used when referring to the day in general (as in your case).

Comment: @Tyler - That said, we'd use _at_ for a more general day, too: "The script should run at the beginning of every month."