# Prepositional Phrase - confused - at or in

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases

Let's meet in the morning  or at the morning.

in the afternoon or at the afternoon.

in the night or at the night.

in the park or at the park.

working in the background or at the background.

Comment: I'd look at this & its links, for whether places & times are considered 'containers' or 'surfaces' - http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/49130/11747

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take them one at a time:

```
Let's meet [in or at] the (morning or afternoon).
```

This is to meet at a *general* time in the next (most immediate) morning. "In" is the correct choice. The resolution applies to both 'morning' and 'afternoon,'
 as each refers to a non-specific time frame.

```
Let's meet [in or at] the night.
```

"The" here is where one might trip. For someone proposing a clandestine effort, to say "Let's meet in the night" is arguably plausible if uncommon. More conventionally, however, one would say "Let's meet at night," with no need to use the definite article "the," as each day has only one night.

```
Let's meet [in or at] the park.
```

You can make a valid case for either preposition. The park is a specific location when seen on a map, but any location within the park is also "in" the park.

```
working (in or at) the background
```

In most contexts, foreground and background are an abstract, relative relationship, not a fixed point, thus making it difficult to rationalize "at." If you have, for example, three layers, the middle is in the foreground relative to the rear-most layer, but in the background relative to the nearest layer. Also, since "working" implies a use of the word "background" in a notional sense of a secondary process or task, not a specific place, I would almost always recommend "in" as the correct choice.

Answer (score 0):

Where is Tia's father? - "He's in Tia's school"
It's not routine, he does not do anything there regularly. But now...

Where is Tia? - "She's at school"
Talks about her routine engagement, daily activity of not just being there, but also study.

Answer (score -1):

There are two questions in this!

Let's take the first one.

### Question one: in/at for the periods

When we talk about a 'point of time' it's generally 'at'. And thus, we see the following examples:

> at 8 o'clock 
>  at midnight (this means 0000 hr) 
>  at noon (1200 hr)... and so on

But when we talk about the 'period', we are not sure 'at what particular point of time' and thus, we see these examples:

> in morning/evening/night etc.

However, we do find 'at night', but then ***I think*** it's used for a regular happening and *not* for that very night. Say...

> The mother *always* tells story to her kid ***at night*** - talking about an 'every-night' activity

But...

> Do you remember, her murder happened ***in the night*** - not a routine, of course!

Nevertheless, *'at night'* was used even for non-routine things, **but** years back, I think.

### Question 2: in/at for the places

Actually, *'in school'* is common in AmE and *'at school'* in BrE.

If I talk about InE I practice,

I'd ***generally*** use 'at' simply to show 'presence'.

> Where is Tia's father? ~ *"He's **at** Tia's school"*

It's **not** routine, he does not do anything there regularly. But now...

> Where is Tia? ~ *"She's **in** school"*

Talks about her routine engagement, daily activity of not just *being* there, but also study.

In India, you quite frequently hear someone asking -- `Which school she's in?` and **never** 'at'.

---

I could not get what 'background' you are talking about. But more or less, the latter piece of my answer shall address it.

Comment: I stopped reading this answer after the passage where you demonstrated the difference between **at night** and **in the night**. I think it's because of the passage that you got the down-vote. **at night** and **in the night** is by no means synonyms; *at night* says about the night in general. On the other hand *in the night* says about the particular time during the night. But still there is practically no difference between these two sentences - **Her mother always tells her story at night** and **Her mother always tells her story in the night**.

Comment: BTW that's not my down-vote though :-)