# "At another time" or "In another time"?

Tags: prepositions

What is acceptable form sentence in the spoken English?

> 1) I will see you **in** another time

or

> 2) I will see you **at** another time

Answer (score 1):

There is an answer [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/54364/on-at-in-as-preposition-of-time) that says, in part,

> we could label *at* as referring to *specific* times, and *in* to refer to relatively nonspecific times (*During* a month, a season, a year, a decade, a century, a nonspecific period of time); while *on* refers to *specific* days and dates.

I would modify *in* to refer to a nonspecific period of time. So I would reject "in another time" since "another time" is not a period of time.

I would choose "at another time" since "another time" is a specific time, even though "another" has no precise meaning.

Comment: This is correct. It's kind of analogous to location: you can be *at* a particular location, or you can be *in* an area.

Comment: You're pretty much right, but at the end of the day I think the question is simply a dup of your link. It's perfectly possible to say, for example, [that was **in** another time](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22that+was+in+another+time%22) (somewhen during some relatively non-specific earlier *age, period*), whereas ***at** another time* means a specific time (often, not too far distant from whatever time it's being contrasted with). If OP were talking to a time-traveler (Dr Who, for example), ***in*** might well be the better choice.

Answer (score 0):

The former is needlessly science-fiction-y, or relativistic, if you will.

The latter is actually correct, but kind of lame.

Normally one would say, "**I'll see you some other time**" and leave it at that.