# In the weekend or on the weekend?

Tags: prepositions, time

> In the weekend

or

> On the weekend

I know various books denote it "**on** the weekend", but I need to know why  "**in** the weekend" cannot be used even if it shows duration.

Comment: The last sentence looks weird @nathan tuggy. Something is missing!

Comment: @RuchirM: True enough, but that's the way it was written, and I didn't feel like my correction would improve the question without losing the writer's voice. (It's also not really wrong, just odd.)

Comment: Related (possibly a duplicate of): [where do people say ON the weekend (geographically speaking)?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/49121/3281)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there doesn't appear to be a great explanation for *why*.  It is just an odd nuance of English that we do things **on** days and **in** months.

> I'll be staying at school on the weekends.

and

> I will return in the month of May.

The following two links give a few more examples.

- [At, on and in (time)](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/at-on-and-in-time)
- [Over the weekend, on the weekend, at the weekend](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/qa/Over-the-weekend-on-the-weekend-at-the-weekend)

Comment: Note that "over the weekend" can show duration, e.g., "She will be traveling over the weekend."  Also, and I won't go too far with this because I'm a U.S. English speaker, "at the weekend" seems more common in British English than in U.S. English.

Comment: To quote the [second link](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/qa/Over-the-weekend-on-the-weekend-at-the-weekend), "At the weekend is a British English expression, which is used the same way as on the weekend in American English. Speakers of American English may understand this expression, but they do not use it."

Comment: What's interesting is . . . I don't think I say "on the weekend" much.  More "this weekend" or "last weekend" or "over the weekend."  It's a good question!

Answer (score 1):

'In the weekend' is [a common ***error***](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/at-on-and-in-time).

A popular confusion is 'on the weekend' **OR** 'at the weekend'.

In that, it's the register that makes the difference. BrE and AmE

[Learner's Dictionary](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/qa/Over-the-weekend-on-the-weekend-at-the-weekend) quotes:

> ***'At the weekend'*** is a *British English* expression, which is used the same way as ***'on the weekend'*** in *American English*. Speakers of American English may understand this expression, but they do not use it.

Comment: what do you mean by this line "the register that makes the difference. BrE and AmE"Can u explain with an example