# differences between Closes and closed

Tags: grammar, grammaticality-in-context

Is there any differences between these sentences:

1. she closes her store during weekends
2. she closed her store during weekends

Comment: It's pretty basic that one is present tense and the other past.

Comment: @Kate Bunting I have a question. Why is the present simple not used with “yesterday” or “tomorrow” but with specific time phrases like “at night” or “on weekends”? The present simple that I’m saying functions as making the general truth/fact.

Comment: @GatePending - 'She closes her store yesterday' doesn't make sense. We can use the present tense to refer to planned future events: 'She closes her store tomorrow' (if it will be closing down for good), or 'I leave for Paris this evening'.

Comment: @Kate Bunting I mean the general truth… But thank you!

Answer (score 0):

#1 is present tense and #2 is past tense.

Note: 'on weekends' is better than 'during weekends'

"She closes her store on weekends." - Her current routine is that when a weekend comes along, she closes her store.

"She closed her store on weekends" - At times in the past, she closed her store on weekends and she no longer does. To me, it implies that she or the store is no longer there or she is no longer in charge of the store. If you wanted to say that her store is now open on weekends but wasn't in the past, I would say "She used to close her store on weekends"

Comment: _Note: 'on weekends' is better than 'during weekends'_  Only if you're American! In British English it's 'at (or during) the weekend'.

Comment: I'm British and I would usually say "It's closed on weekends". I've never heard anyone say "during the weekend" in this context. Maybe it's a regional thing?

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/49121/where-do-people-say-on-the-weekend-geographically-speaking

Comment: In my experience in the UK we use _at_ for weekends but _on_ for a specific named day, _on Sundays_ and for a group of days _on weekdays_. I agree with @KateBunting on _on weekends_ sounds North American to my ears. Perhaps it is a generational thing.